# Memoir Class, Subcaptions, and the List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, subcaption

I've been trying to figure out how on earth to get subfigures produced by the `subcaption` package to show up in the LoF with memoir class.

Memoir evidently includes its own way to create subfigures. However, I'm really reticent to switch to this for several reasons:

1. The documentation for it is extremely confusing and unclear.
2. The syntax is much more tedious and less intuitive than with `subcaption`
3. Getting spacing to work properly is awkward. Every example I've seen just features included graphics and then sets the width with the includedgraphics command. However, for my TiKZ illustrations, this isn't an option. Scaling the image isn't what I want: rather, I want to control the margins. `subcaption` has an very clear cut way to do this. Memoir's internal subfig code makes this really hard for some reason.

Finally: it still isn't clear how to get subfigures to show up even with using the `subbottom` command built into memoir! With subcaption, everything just works and looks great. With subbottom/subtop, I have to fiddle with things in a way that seems totally unnecessary. Adding the `list=true` option doesn't work, subfigures are still absent from the LoF. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: As most of your remarks are remarks about `memoir` I would have found it useful if you had supplied an example MWE of a `subfigure` that you found easy to do with the `subcaption` package but difficult using `memoir`. Perhaps then I could help you (but no guarantees).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `memoir` document class offers two values for specifying the depth of the "List of Figure" and "List of Tables": `lofdepth` and `lotdepth`, and their default value is 1. So setting the option `list=on` (or `list=true`) when loading the `subcaption` package is not sufficient, the corresponsing "depth" value must be changed, too.

For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[list=on]{subcaption}
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{Test}

\begin{figure}    
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering\large A
        \caption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering\large B
        \caption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

P.S.: I should add this to the `subcaption` package documentation. I will open a ticket and resolve it ASAP.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/45/